# Lazy Loading and RequiredAttribute problem: The XXX field is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a `Comment` class with, among others, an `Author` property:

```
public class Comment : IEquatable<Comment>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    // More properties here
}
```

I want users to be able to "like" a comment, much like here at StackOverflow. To that end I have the following action in my `CommentController`:

```
public virtual ActionResult Like(int id)
{
    var comment = _session.Single<Comment>(c => c.ID == id);
    comment.Likes++;

    _session.CommitChanges();

    return Json(new { comment.Likes });
}
```

Whenever I invoke this action I get the following Validation Error:

> The Author field is required.

The `Comment` object comes from the db, so *it does* have an author. The "funny" thing is, whenever I use the Visual Studio debugger to check whether the `Author` really is missing, the validation error does not fire.

Am I correct in assuming here that the problem is that the lazy loading of the `Author` property never takes place? If so, how can I, for this situation only, force all navigation properties to be filled in? (I want to keep working with lazy loading otherwise)

What's the neatest way to solve this? Am I even on the right track?
And why isn't lazy loading happening while EF clearly requires it to save the entity?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's somewhat unusual to put `Required` on a non-string field.  The documentation says *"A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters."*

Comment: @Hightechrider - I'm using Code First, and one of the things the  `RequiredAttribute` does is mark the FK relation as `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which is what I wanted here. And MSDN says about the `RequiredAttribute`: *"Specifies that a **data field value** is required."*. It's not only for strings, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Include`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2008/10/07/migrating-from-linq-to-sql-to-entity-framework-eager-loading.aspx) to eagerly fetch a relation on the data context.

```
context.Comments.Include("Author").Single<Comment>(c => c.ID == id);
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin - Is there any other way? That would force me to go "out" of my Unit of Work implementation and use the `context` directly in my action, which I'd rather not do. It's all so nicely abstracted and loosely coupled now... :)

Comment: I could always add an `EagerSingle<T>()` method to my `ISession` interface I suppose.

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, you could use a service layer encapsulating this logic and exposing a `Like(int commentId)` method. It's not the controller's responsibility to do things like fetching comments,  `Likes++`, updating. All it needs is to call the corresponding service method.

Comment: @Darin - Wouldn't that be overkill in this situation? There's not a lot of code on that action and there's nothing that "really shouldn't be there", is there?

Comment: @Sergi Papaseit, controllers should not be fat. [Put them on a diet](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - True, I know, and +1 for all the good advice. I'm still curious why lazy loading isn't happening while it is clearly required by EF to save the entity.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. The below should work (with LazyLoading enabled).

```
public virtual ActionResult Like(int id)
{

   var comment = _session.Single<Comment>(c => c.ID == id);
   comment.Likes++;

   if(TryUpdateModel(comment))
   {

       _session.CommitChanges();

   }
   return Json(new { comment.Likes });
}
```

Comment: I've tried and this does indeed work. It feels a hacky though. It's more of a workaround than a solution isn't it?

Comment: From my understanding it "merges" the original object with the modified version(this is obviously simplified). So I don't see it too much of a hack. Personally I feel it is better than disabling LazyLoading or creating any other complex workarounds.